# Multiline EditText in RecyclerView scrolling issues

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, android-recyclerview, multiline

I have a `RecyclerView` that contains a multiline `EditText` as a list item, the `EditText` expands each time a line is added. The `RecyclerView` has a standard vertical `LinearLayoutManager` and a standard `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` adapter with 15 of the EditText list items. I'll add the code at the end of the question.

The issue is that after you have added a number of lines to the `EditText`, it begins to scroll the list down each time a line is added. Eventually, after you have added enough new lines, the EditText will be scrolled off the top of the screen and loses focus. If you try to scroll back up and select the last line of the `EditText`, it will scroll the list back down until the `EditText` is off the top of the screen and it loses focus.

This isn't an issue for `ListView`, only for `RecyclerView`.

Does anyone know how to fix or get around this issue?

**The line item:**

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
      android:gravity="top"
      android:hint="Enter text"
      android:minLines="2"
      android:layout_margin="16dp"/>
```

**The RecyclerViewFragment and Adapter**

```
public class RecyclerViewFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_fragment, container, false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        return view;
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
    {
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.edit_text_list_item, parent, false);

            MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount()
        {
            return 15;
        }

        private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView)
            {
                super(itemView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue was fixed by the latest version of the RecyclerView: 22.2.0

Answer (score 0):

```
EditTextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

While Edittext on recycler view,  request to not deliver touch event to its parent. This way editText will have touch event and will behave as expected

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.